# How to find this specific ratio of a point between two line segments?

Tags: line, translation, point, segment

[image]

I have two line segments, defined by points **AB** and **CD** and a point **P**, somewhere inside the irregular square **ABDC**.
I need to find a ratio going from `0` to `1`, depending on where point **P** lies between lines **AB** and **CD**.
If **P** lies anywhere on **AB** it should be `0`, if it lies anywhere on **CD** it should be `1`.
In the illustration it should be around `0.55` to `0.6` I suppose.

If the two lines were parallel I could just measure the distance to both lines, so it would be easy.

I've tried playing around with all kinds of angles and distances between the various points, but I can't seem to find any constant which I could base my function off of.

My guess is that I have to somehow translate line **AB** into **CD** and find the point in the "translation progress" where **P** lies on that "translating" line, exactly at this moment of the translation, if that makes sense..

I struggle to properly explain this problem, but I hope this was somewhat understandable.

Comment: This sounds like a mathematical problem, more than a programming problem.

Comment: I should preface this by saying I'm not a mathematician. However, one sense (and I'm tempted to say, the only one) in which we can relate P to ABCD, is by first considering the points of convergence of AC,BD, and AB, CD - effectively considering ABCD as a rectilinear plane viewed in perspective. However, viewed this way, P is approximately 21/32 in the y axis of the plane, so 0.656, or thereabouts, because of what we might call acceleration.

Comment: @Strawberry This actually helped a lot. I guess thinking outside the box is the key here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Strawberry suggested, I have to calculate the convergence point of **AB** and **CD**. Call this point **X**, then calculate the intersection point of **PX** with **BD** and measure the distance from that intersection point to **B**. This distance divided by the length of **BD** is exactly the ratio I was looking for!

Comment: Glad 'thinking outside the box', as you say, worked out for you ;-)

Comment: Note that CA is irrelevant to this particular calculation